# How can I create a unit test for @Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-test

I'm trying create a test for a redirect that I have in my code:

```
import {DOCUMENT, Location} from '@angular/common';
....
export class BankSlipConfirmationComponent {

constructor(...
          @Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: Document) {
}

...

cancel() {
    this.document.location.href = `${environment.urlMenu}`;
}
```

But I can't find how I can Inject in test file the DOCUMENT, example:

```
...
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    LinkIconeBradescoModule,
    RouterTestingModule,
    ModalMobileBradescoModule
  ],
  declarations: [BankSlipConfirmationComponent, ConfirmationModalComponent],
  providers: [{provider: DOCUMENT, useValue: document}, BankSlipInclusionService]
}).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BankSlipConfirmationComponent);
  router = TestBed.get(Router);
  service = TestBed.get(BankSlipInclusionService);
  service.change(getValidateBankSlipInclusion());
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
it('Test when user click in cancel button', () => {
    component.cancel();
});
```

When I run the test I had received this message:

> console.error
>
> node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
>
> ```
> Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)
>     at module.exports (C:\Desenvolvimento\Quero-Receber-PDPJ\pdpj-fed-account-receivables\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\not-implemented.js:9:17)
>     at navigateFetch (C:\Desenvolvimento\Quero-Receber-PDPJ\pdpj-fed-account-receivables\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\window\navigation.js:77:3)
>     at exports.navigate (C:\Desenvolvimento\Quero-Receber-PDPJ\pdpj-fed-account-receivables\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\window\navigation.js:55:3)
>     at LocationImpl._locationObjectNavigate (C:\Desenvolvimento\Quero-Receber-PDPJ\pdpj-fed-account-receivables\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\window\Location-impl.js:29:5)
>     at LocationImpl._locationObjectSetterNavigate (C:\Desenvolvimento\Quero-Receber-PDPJ\pdpj-fed-account-receivables\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\window\Location-impl.js:23:17)
>     at LocationImpl.set href [as href] (C:\Desenvolvimento\Quero-Receber-PDPJ\pdpj-fed-account-receivables\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\window\Location-impl.js:45:10)
>     at Location.set href [as href] (C:\Desenvolvimento\Quero-Receber-PDPJ\pdpj-fed-account-receivables\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\generated\Location.js:135:29)
>     at BankSlipConfirmationComponent.cancel (C:\Desenvolvimento\Quero-Receber-PDPJ\pdpj-fed-account-receivables\src\app\bank-slip-confirmation\bank-slip-confirmation.component.ts:568:33)
>     at C:\Desenvolvimento\Quero-Receber-PDPJ\pdpj-fed-account-receivables\test\bank-slip-confirmation.component.spec.ts:51:15
>     at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\Desenvolvimento\Quero-Receber-PDPJ\pdpj-fed-account-receivables\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone.js:391:26) undefined
> ```

However, I'm not understanding what is the problem...

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the complete unit test. What is the value of document in the provider? {provider: DOCUMENT, useValue: document}

Comment: Also, it should be `provide` and not `provider` (no r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could skip the following to provide the `DOCUMENT`:

```
{provider: DOCUMENT, useValue: document}
```

The injected `document` can be used directly as follows:

```
let mockDocument: Document;

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BankSlipConfirmationComponent);
  mockDocument = TestBed.inject(DOCUMENT);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this test for a pipe which uses @Inject(DOCUMENT):

```
import { PipeToTest } from './pipe-to-test.pipe';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('PipeToTest', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [BrowserModule],
    });
  });

  it('create an instance', inject([DOCUMENT], (document: Document) => {
    const pipe = new PipeToTest(document);
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

Here is the pipe to test:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: 'appPipeToTest',
})
export class PipeToTest implements PipeTransform {
    private divElement: HTMLDivElement;

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document) {
        this.divElement = document.createElement('div');
    }

    transform(html: string): string {
        ...
        return text === null ? '' : text;
    }
}
```